# Post data using $.post fails with empty data

Tags: jquery

I want to send some data using jQuery

```
var uri = "some url";

$.post(uri,
    { message: "test"},
    {"format" : "json"}, 
    'html');

return false;
```

When the php script gets the request the message field is empty. Why?

---

Edit: I use zend framework to read the post data

```
$this->getRequest ()->getPost ( 'message' );
```

The js code from above workes on localhost but on the server message is empty. I check with `isPost()` which says that there is no post.

Comment: How do you read the variable from the PHP side ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing two objects to `$.post`.  There's no reason to do this.  I think you just want this:

```
$.post(uri,
    { message: "test"},
    'html');
```

The server will understand the format of the posted data.